# Vlookup sum from external spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am trying to create a sort of overview sheet from an external excel sheet, I was using SUMIFS however this was failing whenever I closed the work book... I just cannot get my head around SUMPRODUCT.

[image: Example data]

I would like to have a summary page which will VLOOKUP the against the USER column then sums the PICKED column and define it by what LOCATION it was from. I also wanted to add between times for example 6-7.

[image: Looking for this]

Thank you

Comment: What Excel version are you working with?

Comment: Excel version is 2016

Comment: Are you able to use Power Query?
It'd be an option for getting data from closed workbooks. Let me know if you'd like to see an example with this solution.

Comment: That would be great thank you, I've never heard of power query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

You can access the data of a closed workbook with Power Query.

I'm gonna refer to the files as source workbook (where you have currently stored the data)
and report workbook (the one where you want to generate the sumif report)

Steps:

1- Close the source workbook (this solution works / refreshes when the file is closed only)

2- Activate the report workbook

3- In a blank sheet, Click "Data" | "Get Data" | "From file" | "From workbook"

4- Browse to the source workbook's location and select the file

5- Click Open

6- Click the "DATE / TIME" column header

7- Click on the ribbon: "Add Column" | "Time" | "Hour" | "Start of hour"

8- Click with mouse while pressing the "Control" key on the keyboard to select the columns: USER, FROM, Start of hour

9- Click on the ribbon: "Transform" | "Group by"

10- Change the "New column name" to "Picked_total"

11- Change the "Operation" to Sum

12- Change the "Column" to "Picked"

13- Click "Ok"

14- Click on the ribbon: "Home" | Close & load to

15- Select "Table" and the location where you want to load the data to

To fresh with new data:

Rember to have the source workbook closed

- Right click the table of the loaded data and select refresh

Here is a link to an screencast of the steps:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o53nr.jpg

Let me know if it helps.

---

Please mark this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

So, did this so far:
[image]

Shows how sumifs works using E2 and F2 to control the summed range. Left the dat for you to expand on...

Comment: The trouble I am having is SUMIFS will not work once the data spreadsheet I am using is closed, I am wanting to link to an external workbook.

Comment: seems like SUMIFS() has to have the other spreadsheet open - usually so it has the latest values.